# Is this set of vectors a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

$$V\in\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
a+b \end{bmatrix}$$

$$a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R} $$
$$u, v, w \in V$$

My answer is that the above is a vector space because it satisfies these axioms:

$$u+v=v+u$$
$$u+0=u$$
$$u+(-u)=0$$
$$u+v \in V$$
$$(u+v)+w=(v+w)+u$$
$$cu \in V$$
$$c(u+v)=cu+cv$$
$$(cd)u=d(cu)$$
$$(c+d)u=cu+du$$

I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: $V$ is the plane described by the equation $x+y-z=0.$

Comment: Do you mean that $V$ is the set of all vectors of that form?

Comment: sorry, v is the element of the matrix.

Comment: $V$ is the span of $[1,0,1]^\intercal$ and $[0,1,1]^\intercal$. Hence it is a vector space.

Comment: Usually we do not check all the axioms. For this question, write the set as the span of two vectors, which implies that it is a vector space.